# Use SSIS expresion to break up Full Name in to Seperate fields, Last First Middle

Tags: sql, ssis, transform, etl

I have a full name field that has data in the format of

Last Name First Name Middle Name

some of the data doesn't have a Middle Name where as it will be just

Last Name First Name

also some of the data has 2 spaces between the Last Name and First Name where as it comes to be

Last Name  First Name

all of this data is in the same field, how would I go about breaking this data up in to 3 seperate fields using an SSIS Expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have a bad experience here because of names like "De los Santos Edwin Paul" or any of a host of multi surname conditions.

I advocate using multiple derived columns in cases like this to help you identify where things have gone wrong for future debugging.

A assume the name data column is called `NameFull`.

### DER SubDoubleSpaces

The first thing I would do is simplify your life. Instead of writing two conditionals for one space and two space between Last name and First name, I'd make everything consistent with one space.

Create a new column via a Derived Column Component called `Name` and we're going to replace all the double spaces with a single one.

```
REPLACE([NameFull], "  ", " ")
```

### DER GetFirstSpace

Add a new derived column component to the Data flow. Add a new column, called `FirstSpace`. The expression we want to use is [FINDSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
FINDSTRING([Name], " ", 1)
```

### DER GetLastName

Add another derived column component into the mix. This will use the value of our new column `FirstSpace` to slice out the first element and I'll stuff it into a column called `LastName`

```
SUBSTRING([Name], 1, [FirstSpace])
```

### DER GetSecondSpace

Add a new derived column component to the Data flow. Add a new column, called `SecondSpace`. The expression we want to use is similar to the first but the third parameter will be the position of the last space we found (plus 1 to skip it)

```
FINDSTRING([Name], " ", [FirstSpace])
```

### DER GetSecondName

Similar to the LastName except now we'll use the First and Second spaces

```
SUBSTRING([Name], [FirstSpace]+1, [SecondSpace])
```

### DER MiddleName

At this point, you can see the pattern but now we have to deal with your actual data, which I don't have. What if they don't have a middle name listed? The lazy/safe approach for middle name is probably to add a derived column and just take the RIGHTmost N characters. If they have a middle name, this will pick it up, otherwise, it should just blank it out.

```
RIGHT([Name], LEN([Name]) - [SecondSpace] +1)
```

Answers with similar approach

- [SSIS Substring Error Using Case When with Right Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66157797/ssis-substring-error-using-case-when-with-right-function/66160220#66160220)
- [How can I turn a string into a decimal in SSIS using a derived column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906618/how-can-i-turn-a-string-into-a-decimal-in-ssis-using-a-derived-column/66907923#66907923)

Comment: thank you! But in the event there is ever a fourth name how would the expression change?

Comment: You would extend the pattern - Add a `DER GetThirdSpace` and a corresponding `DER GetThirdName`