# How to convert datetime which is in Text format in Excel to yyyy-mm-dd HH-MM-ss in ssis derived column Expression

Tags: ssis

I was trying this expression but still getting error

```
((DT_STR,4000,1252)(LEFT(TOKEN([Date] ,"/",1),4) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN([Date] ,"/",2),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN([Date] ,"/",3),2) + " " ++ " " + TOKEN([Date] ,":",4)+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN([Date] ,":",5),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN([Date] ,":",6),2)))
```

Comment: What is your actual and desired output ?

Comment: Don't attempt this in a single pass. How can you tell whether it's the getting of a year or the hour that is breaking? You cannot. Instead, make 6 precursor Derived Column Components, each one with a single task - make Year, Make Month, etc In the final one, combine them all to make your desired string. Put a Data Viewer between the penultimate and ultimate Derived Column and visually inspect the values - are you getting what you expected? If not, then you know where to focus your debugging efforts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927002/181965 Sample Answer with multiple Derived col pattern

Comment: FYI... MM = month and mm=minute

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a script task. This assumes your string will always Parse to a DateTime. If not, look into `TryParse()`.

Also, ParseExact() is even better but you didn't provide an example.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(your date string);
string dtFormatted = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

I will add one more caveat. You should probably treat this as a date and only format the date on the presentation layer.